# ASP.Net MVC with Razor and ASPX view engine both in one project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Can we use both Razor and ASPX view engine in one asp.net mvc project?

For example, 
Controller1 will use cshtml page
Controller2 will use aspx view.

or can we change viewengine type dynamically?

Comment: Yes it can, we do it. Sorry that's doesn't help you much but it at least gives you hope!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this [ASP.NET MVC Blog Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/29/asp-net-mvc-3-using-multiple-view-engines-in-same-project.aspx) should give you what you're after.

Comment: Yes you are right, I want to know answer weather it is possible or not,you know like idea in mind.
But now as Conclusion of your given link, It is not good idea to use both view engine in project.
I have views some written in Razor and some in aspx, so better for me is to convert all to in one format.
once again thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely a bad idea to have multiple engines, at least until you can transition to Razor for all your views.

Answer (score 0):

i built my application on razor view so my default view file is Index.cshtml.. instead of that i use LIST.aspx view and this is how you cold do. it is easy just specify as below

```
public ActionResult Index() // this is Index Action
{
    var employees = db.Employees.Include("Department");//e => e.
    return View("LIST",employees.ToList()); // syntax this how u can use ASPX.view "LIST" is an ASPX View file in my application. 
}
```

let me know if you have an error or anything